# Rendered image turns out different than preview, using BLENDER RENDER

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new with Blender, but I've created a scene I'm happy with when I preview it. However, when I actually render the image, it turns out different - not just darker, but with some shapes appearing shorter than they really are. What gives?

I am using Blender Render and not Cycles, so all of the tutorials and forum posts I find online are for a different engine.

Where do I begin?
[image: Before pic]

[image: After pic]

Comment: Can you add images showing the difference? Also check that there is nothing set up in the compositor

Comment: You can begin by adding more information, so that someone can help you. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to edit your post and explain what you did, what kind of render settings you are using, etc. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I have added screenshots of before and after, I am pretty new with Blender so not sure which settings are relevant, let me know if I should post anything that's not in the photos. Thanks!

Comment: You have elements that are disabled for preview (eye icon) but are enabled for rendering (camera icon)

Comment: Is this the reason my image turns out differently? I only have one hidden object, but it does not show when rendering.

Comment: Ok, I've been playing around with it, and I've made a discovery - the weird black squares that cover up the image on the sides are the smoke/fire effects - once I disable them from rendering, it looks fine. How can I keep the fire effect without creating those black squares?